# Ssrs sql report - dynamics crm record sharepoint document location

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I have a field in my ssrs dynamics crm report using sql which runs against a case, I need it to display the URL for the sharepoint location for documents related to that case.

Has anyone got any experience and can help on using the correct tables in order to create a expressions which displays the correct URL related for that case for its document location.

Answer (score 0):

`sharepointdocumentlocation` is the entity which will store document URL in `relativeurl` attribute. You have to look for case guid in `regardingobjectid`

Check `absoluteurl` for fully qualified navigation link. These are totally up to your project for values.

Edit:
From this [forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/200654) & [thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/215127), Its clear that CRM does not have OOB way to store this. Need to write custom code to update a field on record or [custom code](http://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/10/retrieve-absolute-and-site-collection-url-request-in-dynamics-crm/)/query to retrieve absolute URL.

For sharepoint site details, query the `sharepointsite` entity for `absoluteurl` or `relativeurl`.

Comment: Does this attribute have the full URL so users can click as hyperlink?

Comment: That's based on your project. You didn't show us how your sample record look like. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/create-or-edit-document-location-records.aspx

Comment: Anyway possible using expression?

Comment: Using expression, try like concat "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/.../Shared%20Documents"... to get your actual path. You can get this from your CRM SP settings..

Comment: Any idea what tables and attributes can be used to make this string expression?

Comment: If you are not from CRM team, contact your CRM team member to get basic details like this.